# texreg in Rmarkdown/knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, texreg

Simple question: can I use `texreg` in a markdown (not LaTex) document in Rmarkdown using `knitr`?

I thought I could, but it seems I'm wrong? I can include LaTex code within Rmarkdown for equations but have no success for tables with `texreg` (at least when the remaining document is written in markdown.

I get this error:

```
pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

Irrespectively of whether I use `texreg()` (for LatTex), `htmlreg()`, or `screenreg()`, I don't get a decent table in the knitted PDF document.

```
---
title: "Title"
fontsize: 12pt
output:
   pdf_document:
   latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Then trying to develop a table:

````
```{r Table_with_texreg, results="asis"}
library(texreg)
modellist = list(model1, model2, model3, model4, model5)

texreg(modellist, type = 'un', 
summaries = c('ChiSqM_Value', 'ChiSqM_DF', 'ChiSqM_DF', 'ChiSqM_PValue', 'CFI',
'RMSEA_Estimate'), single.row=TRUE)
````

(Some of the arguments after `texreg()` are commands for the `MplusAutomation` package, specifying which parameters (unstandardized) and which model fit indices to use. Shouldn't be of any significance for the question/post.)

This is the LaTex code generated when knitting, resulting in coversion error 43:

```
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c }
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 & Model 5 \\
\hline
 DISCRIM$<$-AGEA           & $-0.00 \; (0.00)^{***}$ & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ & $-0.00 \; (0.00)^{***}$ & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ \\
 DISCRIM$<$-GNDR           & $0.05 \; (0.02)^{**}$   & $0.07 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.09 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.03 \; (0.02)^{*}$    & $0.07 \; (0.02)^{***}$  \\
 DISCRIM$<$-MINORITY       & $0.14 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.17 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.13 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.19 \; (0.04)^{***}$  & $0.19 \; (0.04)^{***}$  \\
 PDJSEX\_R$<$-AGEA         & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ &                         &                         & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ &                         \\
 PDJSEX\_R$<$-GNDR         & $0.38 \; (0.03)^{***}$  &                         &                         & $0.38 \; (0.03)^{***}$  &                         \\
 PDJSEX\_R$<$-MINORITY     & $0.11 \; (0.04)^{**}$   &                         &                         & $0.11 \; (0.04)^{**}$   &                         \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-AGEA         & $-0.00 \; (0.00)^{***}$ &                         & $-0.00 \; (0.00)^{***}$ &                         &                         \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-GNDR         & $-0.02 \; (0.02)$       &                         & $-0.02 \; (0.02)$       &                         &                         \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-MINORITY     & $0.94 \; (0.08)^{***}$  &                         & $0.93 \; (0.08)^{***}$  &                         &                         \\
 PREDJ\_R$<$-DISCRIM       & $1.00 \; (0.00)$        & $1.00 \; (0.00)$        & $1.00 \; (0.00)$        & $1.00 \; (0.00)$        & $1.00 \; (0.00)$        \\
 LKRSP\_R$<$-DISCRIM       & $1.05 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.08 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.08 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.08 \; (0.01)^{***}$  &                         \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-DISCRIM       & $1.02 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.05 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.05 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.05 \; (0.01)^{***}$  &                         \\
 PDJSEX\_R$<$-$>$DISCRIM   & $0.74 \; (0.02)^{***}$  &                         &                         & $0.76 \; (0.02)^{***}$  &                         \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-$>$DISCRIM   & $0.62 \; (0.02)^{***}$  &                         & $0.66 \; (0.02)^{***}$  &                         &                         \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-$>$PDJSEX\_R & $0.78 \; (0.02)^{***}$  &                         &                         &                         &                         \\
 PREDJ_R$1<-Thresholds     & $0.19 \; (0.10)^{*}$    & $0.19 \; (0.10)^{*}$    & $0.18 \; (0.10)$        & $0.18 \; (0.10)$        & $0.18 \; (0.10)$        \\
 PREDJ_R$2<-Thresholds     & $0.71 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.71 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.70 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.70 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $0.70 \; (0.09)^{***}$  \\
 LKRSP_R$1<-Thresholds     & $0.14 \; (0.07)$        & $0.13 \; (0.07)$        & $0.15 \; (0.07)^{*}$    & $0.14 \; (0.07)$        & $0.14 \; (0.07)$        \\
 LKRSP_R$2<-Thresholds     & $0.72 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.72 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.73 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.72 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.72 \; (0.07)^{***}$  \\
 TRTBD_R$1<-Thresholds     & $0.51 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.51 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.50 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.51 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.50 \; (0.06)^{***}$  \\
 TRTBD_R$2<-Thresholds     & $1.11 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $1.11 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $1.12 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $1.11 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $1.11 \; (0.07)^{***}$  \\
 PDJSEX_R$1<-Thresholds    & $0.86 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.86 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.87 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.86 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $0.86 \; (0.06)^{***}$  \\
 PDJSEX_R$2<-Thresholds    & $1.44 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $1.44 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $1.44 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $1.44 \; (0.06)^{***}$  & $1.44 \; (0.06)^{***}$  \\
 PDJETN_R$1<-Thresholds    & $0.80 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.79 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.80 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.79 \; (0.07)^{***}$  & $0.80 \; (0.07)^{***}$  \\
 PDJETN_R$2<-Thresholds    & $1.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $1.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $1.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $1.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  & $1.29 \; (0.09)^{***}$  \\
 DISCRIM$<$-$>$DISCRIM     & $0.79 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.74 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.74 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.75 \; (0.02)^{***}$  & $0.84 \; (0.01)^{***}$  \\
 PDJSEX\_R$<$-DISCRIM      &                         & $1.03 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $1.03 \; (0.01)^{***}$  &                         & $0.98 \; (0.01)^{***}$  \\
 PDJETN\_R$<$-DISCRIM      &                         & $0.90 \; (0.01)^{***}$  &                         & $0.90 \; (0.01)^{***}$  & $0.87 \; (0.01)^{***}$  \\
 LKRSP\_R$<$-AGEA          &                         &                         &                         &                         & $-0.01 \; (0.00)^{***}$ \\
 LKRSP\_R$<$-GNDR          &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.06 \; (0.02)^{***}$  \\
 LKRSP\_R$<$-MINORITY      &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.14 \; (0.04)^{***}$  \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-AGEA          &                         &                         &                         &                         & $-0.00 \; (0.00)^{**}$  \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-GNDR          &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.06 \; (0.02)^{**}$   \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-MINORITY      &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.20 \; (0.05)^{***}$  \\
 LKRSP\_R$<$-$>$DISCRIM    &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.74 \; (0.02)^{***}$  \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-$>$DISCRIM    &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.72 \; (0.02)^{***}$  \\
 TRTBD\_R$<$-$>$LKRSP\_R   &                         &                         &                         &                         & $0.88 \; (0.01)^{***}$  \\
\hline
ChiSqM_Value               & 331.41                  & 808.73                  & 776.77                  & 568.88                  & 648.83                  \\
ChiSqM_DF                  & 10                      & 17                      & 14                      & 14                      & 10                      \\
ChiSqM_PValue              & 0.00                    & 0.00                    & 0.00                    & 0.00                    & 0.00                    \\
CFI                        & 0.97                    & 0.93                    & 0.94                    & 0.95                    & 0.95                    \\
RMSEA_Estimate             & 0.02                    & 0.03                    & 0.03                    & 0.03                    & 0.03                    \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
```

P.S. Knitting to HTML (not PDF) and using htmlreg (not texreg) seems to work fine. I would have preferred to use PDF, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing that you want to generate a PDF, but not use `LaTeX`. Are you sure about this? I don't know how to do that, but here are two solutions for generating a) HTML output and b) PDFs with LaTeX, both using `texreg`:

Solution 1 (for HTML output):

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)

library("texreg")
```

Some equation:
$$a + b = 2$$

Table follows:
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
htmlreg(lm.D9, star.symbol = "\\*", doctype = FALSE, center = FALSE, caption = "")
```
````

Here is the output:

[image: HTML output]

Solution 2 (for PDF output):

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)

library("texreg")
```

Some equation:
$$a + b = 2$$

Table follows:
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
texreg(lm.D9, table = FALSE, use.packages = FALSE)
```
````

Here is the output:

[image: PDF output]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and thanks for developing a great package! Maybe I have to use LaTex. After just having learned the basics of R, I find learning LaTex as well is a pretty steep learning curve. (Generating PDF is no problem in Rmarkdown unless I add the table.) Thanks for the code!

Comment: Of course! Glad you find it useful! To be honest, though, I don't see why you would think that the second solution has a steeper learning curve. You still write Markdown code, it's just converted to LaTeX internally because you want to generate a PDF. As you can see, the code for both solutions is very similar.

Comment: Thanks, your code works fine when knitting to PDF, but not mine... I added the LaTex code generated by texreg, this code results in a conversion error.

Comment: Thanks for providing a more detailed example in your updated question. You need to double-escaped underscores and the like. E.g., instead of `\_`, you should write `\\_` in the coefficient names. You can use the `custom.coef.names` argument to do that if you don't want to change the coefficient names inside your model. I don't know if that's the only problem, but that's definitely a show-stopper. If you need more help, you should provide a minimal self-contained example that reproduces your table from scratch.

Comment: I think there are more problems in the coefficient names. For example, in `PREDJ_R$1<-Thresholds`, there is both an unescaped underscore and a single `$`, which usually tells LaTeX that it should expect some math to follow -- but you don't close the inline math block.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your patience! The code in question is generated automatically by the MplusAutomation package, I have informed the developers of your comment.